# Flutter Error Provider context != null': is not true

Tags: android, flutter, dart, package, flutter-provider

```
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  body: Center(
    child: BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => BlocProvider.of<LoginBloc>(_)..add(LoginSubmit(_usernameController.text, _passwordController.text)),
      // create: (context) => LoginBloc(BlocProvider.of<AuthBloc>(context)).add(LoginSubmit(_usernameController.text, _passwordController.text)),
      // create: (context) => BlocProvider.of<LoginBloc>(context, listen: false).add(LoginSubmit(_usernameController.text, _passwordController.text)),

      child: BlocConsumer<LoginBloc, LoginState>(listener: (context, state) async {
        if (state is LoginFailed) {
          CustomeAlertDialog.show(context, "", state.error, key: null);
        }

        if (state is LoginState) {
          //   routes:
          //   <String, WidgetBuilder>{
          //     '/dashboard': (BuildContext context) => new Dashboard(),
          //   };
          //   Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Dashboard()));
          //   // Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, Dashboard.tag, ModalRoute.withName('/'));
        }
      }
```

my VSCode debug console

_LoginPageState.build.

package:flutter123/login_page.dart:107

---

Codeline 107 :

---

create: (context) => BlocProvider.of(_)..add(LoginSubmit(_usernameController.text, _passwordController.text)),

I'm stuck on this error, I've tried the method, I'm still stuck on this error, please help

Comment: Where are you facing with this error?

Comment: its the provider's context you are passing, try using the scaffold's context. Rename both provider's context to something else for ease.

Comment: Error Line 107 : create: (context) => BlocProvider.of<LoginBloc>(_)..add(LoginSubmit(_usernameController.text, _passwordController.text)),

Comment: can you please help, what is the code example? I'm for the first time in darts and it's my first time using the concept of oop